# URL Redirect and Bulk Actions in wp_list_table

Tags: redirect, headers, wp-redirect, wp-list-table, bulk

I am using [the Custom List Table Example plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) as a basis to create my own custom list table. Everything is great, except one thorny point.

When I am processing bulk actions via the `process_bulk_action()` method, I would like to redirect using `wp_redirect()`. Here is an example:

```
function process_bulk_action() {

    // Some security check code here

    // Get the bulk action
    $action = $this->current_action();

    if ($action == 'bulk_trash') {

        // Code for the "delete process"

        // Assuming "delete process" is successful
        wp_redirect("http://url/path.php?update=1&message=some_message");
        exit;
    }

}
```

Please note, in the call `wp_redirect("http://url/path.php?update=1&message=some_message")`, I am trying to redirect to the same page that displays the list table in order to reload it with the result of the trash process. Also note that there is a `message` in the path that allows me to display a notification to the user regarding the result of the bulk action.

The problem is, I get an error message `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by <file path>`.

I understand what the message means, and the reasons behind it (the page is already loaded and cannot be redirected). However, how do I redirect then if I would like to do that after I process the bulk action? If redirect is not the correct solution, what other options do I have that allow me to re-load the custom `wp_list_table` again so that the listed records reflect items being deleted (i.e., less published items, and more items in trash)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Understand hierarchy, You don't need to redirect as form are posting values on same page.

```
function process_bulk_action() {

    // Some security check code here

    // Get the bulk action
    $action = $this->current_action();

    if ($action == 'bulk_trash') {

        // Code for the "delete process" 
       $delete_ids = esc_sql($_POST['bulk-delete']);

       //loop over the array of record ids
       foreach($delete_ids as $id) {
            self::delete_item($id);
       }

       // show admin notice
       echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible"><p>Bulk Deleted..</p></div>';
   }

}
```

another method is prepare_items

```
public function prepare_items() {
      // first check for action
      $this->process_bulk_action();

      // then code to render your view.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need process you bulk actions in admin_action_{ACTION_NAME} hook. Not in wp_list_table class. Read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_action__requestaction/)

Comment: don't work with action2 from bottom of list table :(

Answer (score -3):

echo 'document.location="'http://url/path.php?update=1&message=some_message'";';
This solved my problem

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please do not just dump code but explain how and what it does so people can actually learn instead of just Copy&Paste code.